# Requiring Active_record 4.1.8 gives warnings

Tags: activerecord, bigdecimal

I upgraded to 4.1.8 and now when I open a console session and do `require "active_record"` I get the following output:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'active_record'
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::BASE
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_ALL
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_NaN
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_INFINITY
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_UNDERFLOW
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_OVERFLOW
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_ZERODIVIDE
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_MODE
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_UP
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_DOWN
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_UP
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_DOWN
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_CEILING
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_FLOOR
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_EVEN
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NaN
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_POSITIVE_ZERO
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NEGATIVE_ZERO
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_POSITIVE_FINITE
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NEGATIVE_FINITE
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_POSITIVE_INFINITE
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NEGATIVE_INFINITE
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::INFINITY
/Users/fzondlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/bigdecimal-1.2.5/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::NAN
=> true
```

I've tried reinstalling Active Record 4.1.8 twice now, and both times I get the same issue. I also just tried reinstalling bigdecimal

```
gem uninstall bigdecimal
gem install bigdecimal
```

and that did not fix it. I have bigdecimal-1.2.5 installed currently.

Comment: I guess it's a problem with bigdecimal v 1.2.5 gem. I forced it to use version 1.1 and that has fixed the issue for now. Hope this helps someone else as well.