# How to resolve BigDecimal 'already initialised constant' warnings on 'mailcatcher' cmd?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rubygems, mailcatcher

Every time I start mailcatcher I'm shown 'already initialised constant' warnings. Can anyone advise how to resolve the issue? Thanks. *Update below.*

```
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::BASE
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_ALL
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_NaN
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_INFINITY
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_UNDERFLOW
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_OVERFLOW
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_ZERODIVIDE
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_MODE
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_UP
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_DOWN
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_UP
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_DOWN
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_CEILING
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_FLOOR
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_EVEN
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NaN
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_POSITIVE_ZERO
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NEGATIVE_ZERO
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_POSITIVE_FINITE
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NEGATIVE_FINITE
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_POSITIVE_INFINITE
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NEGATIVE_INFINITE
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::INFINITY
/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bigdecimal-1.2.7/bigdecimal.bundle: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::NAN
```

*Update:* I've `uninstalled gem bigdecimal` and `installed gem bigdecimal`, no change. I've then specified `gem 'bigdecimal', ~> 1.1`, still no change. Not much around on searches for this error. I'm running Ruby 2.1.5 and Rails 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a problem with the bigdecimal gem. Try forcing v1.1 in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bigdecimal', '~> 1.1'
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27557822/1766140).

Comment: Bundle shows that I'm already using bigdecimal 1.2.7. Gem 'bigdecimal' was never specified in Gemfile though, now tried specifying as detailed, but no change. Still showing the deprecation warnings, little of use found from googling around on this so far.

Comment: Did you try 'gem uninstall bigdecimal' and then 'gem install bigdecimal -v 1.1'? I'm getting errors trying to install that version, so will probably move on for the time being as this is an annoyance more than urgent for me, but successfully downgrading seems like will help.